# Capturar os dados correspondente ao index no banco

Tags: android, regex, sqlite, listview

Eu consegui alimentar minha listview com dados do SQLite, porém, eu quero agora capturar os dados (no banco) que cada linha da listview corresponde.

Por exemplo:

Linha 10 exibe Cód. 1 e Nome: Felipe 
Linha 13 exibe Cód. 4 e Nome: Giovana

Por exemplo, aí possui 2 linhas da list, o método que eu consegui utilizar, me retornou uma String com a linha completa. Assim que eu clicar em uma linha da listview, eu quero que ela me retorne o código (Cod.4, por exemplo) que está sendo mostrado na String guardada no adapter. Por exemplo, quero clicar na linha 10 e que ela me informe que os dados que ela está exibindo, correspondem ao registro de código 1 do banco.

Como são 2 colunas que estão sendo exibidas, quero uma forma de capturar elas separadamente.

Estou alimentando a lisview assim:

```
while(data.moveToNext()){
    //coluna 1 do banco

    theList.add("Cód.: " + data.getString(0) + "      " + "Nome: " + data.getString(1));
    ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, theList);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Felipe, tá ruim de entender o que você quer fazer. Pode [edit] a pergunta e tentar ser um pouco mais específico? Aliás, tente dar um título descritivo para sua publicação.

Comment: Sim, farei isso.

Comment: Pra ser sincero, agora eu entendi o que você quer fazer. Acho que só precisa mudar o título e mostrar como você está fazendo pra capturar os dados quando clica, qual o valor retornado e qual o valor que você precisa.

Comment: Em vez de um ArrayAdapter use um CursorAdapter.

Comment: Pessoal, vi em outro lugar que estou alimentando minha listview com String ao invés de objetos, irei alterar aqui

Answer (score 1):

Você deve implementar o método `onItemClickListener()`, usando a posição retornada (`int position`) pelo adapter, recupere a String. Em seguida, utilize [Regex](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) para extrair o número que refere ao código e faça a busca que você quer no banco:

```
private OnItemClickListener mMessageClickedHandler = new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        // extrai com regex o codigo
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\s(\d+)\s");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(parent.getSelectedItem());
        boolean found = m.find();
        String cod = "";
        if (found){
            cod = m.group(1); // testa se é este grupo mesmo ou 0
        }else{} // Algum tratamento de erro

        // Faça a busca no banco através de uma Asynctask<> por exemplo.

    }
};

listView.setOnItemClickListener(mMessageClickedHandler);
```

Pronto, a variavel `cod` tem o código do registro no banco e você pode utilizar para fazer a busca no BD.

PS. Caso queira testar algum padrão `regex`, utilize este [site](https://regex101.com/r/dC8nN5/1), eu recomendo.